# How to add two Arrays.asList() in a new list in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have two lists as below which contains a list of objects of another class. I need to create a third list with the combined value of these two.

```
playerA = Arrays.asList(); 
playerB = Arrays.asList();
```

Comment: Use the copy-constructor and the `addAll()` method: `combo = new ArrayList<>(playerA); combo.addAll(playerB)`

Comment: List<T> bothPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
bothPlayers.addAll(playerA);
bothPlayers.addAll(playerB);

Comment: Thanks! It worked :)